# Render/Add quill editor on click of a button in react

Tags: reactjs, quill, react-quill

I am stuck on this for a day now.
Have read multiple answers but could not find anything.

My task is simple, I have a page where a user can answer a question.

- The page will have two editors open(by default). (Found [this](https://codepen.io/alexkrolick/pen/mMOPmv?editors=0010) in a [react-quill GitHub discussion](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill/issues/252)).
- There will be an 'Add step' button which will, of course, add another quill editor below and the user can add as many steps as he/she likes.
- The editors will have a 'Delete' button alongside it to delete the editors, except for the first two editors.

Now, I want to store the said steps separately in my DB as well, but the `onClick` on the editor does not have `e.target`, instead, it just gives the HTML value. Therefore, how can I add editors onClick and separate the value from the multiple editors?

Any direction or hint towards the solution would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have separate values by using **Array of Objects**.

It can be done by having two separate components,

1. One for RichText Editor,
2. A main component that has a state (Array of Objects)

I used [react-quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill) library for text editor and [react-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap) for styling in the following code. You can replace one or both of them of your choice

**Create two components:**

```
 - App.js // Main component
 - ReactQuill.js // Editor component
```

**ReactQuill.js**

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
    
    import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
    
    class ReactQuillEditor extends React.Component {
      render() {
        const { response, handleChange } = this.props;
        return (
          <ReactQuill
            style={{ marginTop: "4px" }}
            value={response}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default ReactQuillEditor;
```

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

// Editor Component
import Editor from "./components/ReactQuill";

export default function App() {
  const [steps, setStep] = useState([
    {
      step: 1,
      response: ""
    },
    {
      step: 2,
      response: ""
    }
  ]); // For Default Two Inputs

  const handleChange = (value, index) => {

    // Updates, Remove and Replaces an object at index n
    const steptoReplace = steps[index];
    steptoReplace.response = value;

    steps.splice(index, 1);
    steps.splice(index, 0, steptoReplace);

    setStep(steps);
  };

 // Adds an empty entry
  const addStep = () => {
    setStep([
      ...steps,
      {
        step: steps.length + 1,
        response: ""
      }
    ]);
  };

  const reduceStep = () => {
    // To have Two text editor always
    if (steps.length > 2) {
      steps.pop();
      setStep([...steps]);
    }
  };

  const submit = () => {
    // You will have an Array of Objects of all steps
    console.log("steps", steps);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Multiple React Quill</h1>
      <div className="mt-4">
        {steps.map((step, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            Step {index + 1}
            <Editor
              response={step.response}
              handleChange={(value) => handleChange(value, index)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}

        <div className="d-flex mt-4  justify-content-between">
          <Button onClick={addStep}>Add Step </Button>
          <Button onClick={reduceStep}>Remove Step</Button>
        </div>

        <Button className="mt-4" onClick={() => submit()}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Mohamed. I wont be able to test the solution for a day or two, but will def get back if this works or if I have any doubts regarding this.

Comment: This works, just one thing: I used `value = {response || ''}` in `Editor.js` because I was accessing the value of component before `onChange` is called. Thanks for your time.